# How to rename a .txt file in chronological order? (JavaScript or PowerShell)

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

Does anyone know how to write a script (in Java or for use in Powershell) to rename a batch of `.txt` files for them to count up in chronological order? Ex I need it to start at C1_1+100.txt, C1_1+200.txt, C1_1+300.txt ... all the way to +900.txt and then roll over to C1_2+000.txt, C1_2+100.txt ... and so on, this will go all the way to C1_28+900.txt?

The date and time of the `.txt` files don't matter. Just the data within them. All the Files are in a folder on a USB drive.

I was trying to use a program called "Advanced Renamer" to rename them, but it couldn't rename them how I wanted (C1_1+100.txt, C1_1+200.txt, C1_1+300.txt ...), But this program will accept JavaScripts to aid in doing this. I'll attach an image [Profile example in Advanced Renamer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTm0Q.jpg) of the original file name (Profile1.txt, Profile2.txt, Profile3.txt) and the example of how I want it to look in the image. I did a manual override for the three as an example. However, I have to rename about 2700 files and doing that one at a time is torturous.

Any help with this would be super beneficial.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) some examples of the _exact_ file names you currently have, ii) what you want those files to be renamed to, iii) explain if we need to use the modification date of the file or something in the file name to get the date and iv) what should happen if two files have the same data so will have the same file name.

Comment: The files are originally "Profile 1", "Profile 2", "Profile 3"... I am trying to name them based on KP points. They are as followed in the above question. The date/time doesn't matter as only the text within the file is important.

Comment: @StephenCrotty What are KP files? Can you [edit] your question to provide a representative example of the file format?

Comment: @grooveplex I just edited. I hope this will help. 

It's not KP files, its KP points, its just a way we describe certain areas along a cable route. For example, Profile1 would be considered KP1 along the route and that's what I would need renamed "C1_1+100.txt"

Comment: Everything about your question seems like you're using Windows...?

Comment: @Zanna Correct, I am using a windows based computer.

Comment: This site is for questions about Ubuntu. For Windows, ask on our sister site [SU]

Answer (score 3):

I have written a bash script to rename all the `.txt` files as defined in question.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

let "i=0"
let "j=0"

for F in /test-directory/*.txt
do
    if [ $i -gt 9 ]       #if value of i goes beyond 9   
    then
        i=0              #resets the value of i in order to have file names like 000-900
        j=$((j+1))
    fi

    mv "$F" /test-directory/C1_"$j"+"$i"00.txt #rename file
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: the program uses Javascript. Not sure what this one have provided me with is coded in.